# c# Converting cp1255 encoding to utf8

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding

I need to parse a csv file I got, I realized when parsing it all the characters were corrupted After some investigating it seems the file is encoded with cp1255, I would rather avoid having to create my own encoder, Is there a different way to read the file with c# or convert it to utf8?

Edit:

```
private static Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
....

  var textReader = new StreamReader(reportCsv, encoding);
  var csv = new CsvReader(textReader, new Configuration { BadDataFound = null, Delimiter = delimiter, Encoding = encoding });
```

I have tried all the encoding c# found me and nothing.. after using tools to detect what encoding was used in that file I found it was encoded in cp1255.. And I don't think I have a decoder/encoder for that.

I'm using CsvHelper lib to read the CSV file But I believe the problem starts with the StreamReader.

Comment: Show us how you're reading the file, then you might get a useful, targeted answer.

Comment: Relevant: [Convert a string's character encoding from windows-1252 to utf-8](//stackoverflow.com/q/5568033)

Comment: You can read an encoded text file with [`File.ReadAllText(path, encoding)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143369(v=vs.110).aspx), so you might choose to read it with `File.ReadAllText(path,Encoding.GetEncoding(1255))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read text files with ANSI encoding and non-English letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130290/how-to-read-text-files-with-ansi-encoding-and-non-english-letters)

Comment: In light of your edit... Why not use `Encoding.GetEncoding(1255)` instead of `Encoding.UTF8`?

Comment: I'm getting an exception NotSupportedException: No data is available for encoding 1255. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method. I thought it doesn't exist, Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to you did not paste any code it is hard to help...

But every File function in c# has got an encoding parameter where you can specify the encoding of the file you are reading eg.:

[File.ReadAllLines(String, Encoding)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsy4fhsa(v=vs.110).aspx)

An Encoding can be created using the Encoding class, eg. for cp850:

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(850);
```

You can read more about encodings (nice article) [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding).

Additionally wondering why you want to convert it to utf-8? c# is native utf-16.

**EDIT**

Due to the project is based on .net core additional codepage registration according to this [so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870084/net-core-doesnt-know-about-windows-1252-how-to-fix) was necessary.

Comment: If I am trying to do Encoding.GetEncoding(1255) I'm getting NotSupportedException: No data is available for encoding 1255. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.

Comment: Please take a look at the documentation of [Encoding.GetEncodings()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getencodings(v=vs.110).aspx). Inside this article is sample code to retrieve all encodings which your operating system does currently support

Comment: I tried that approach, But got very few results which were not relevant, Could it be because I'm using .Net Core?

Comment: Indeed, please try the approach described in this [so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870084/net-core-doesnt-know-about-windows-1252-how-to-fix)

Comment: I see, Thanks for your answer I wouldn't think about it if you didn't brainstorm with me =), Please write your answer and I will mark it as answered.